# CSingleLock implementation works ok on Windows 7 but ends in a deadlock on Win XP

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I've tried substituting MFC's CSingleLock implementation with my own, but I now have a deadlock on windows XP which I don't have on windows 7 and which I did not have on either OSs with MFC's CSingleLock, besides looking into every Lock & Unlock in my app, what is missing from my implementation:

```
class CCriticalSection
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs; 
public:
    CCriticalSection()
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }
    ~CCriticalSection()
    {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }
    void Lock()
    {   
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }
    BOOL TryLock()
    {
        return TryEnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }
    void Unlock()
    {
         if(m_cs.LockCount > -1)
              LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }
};
```

and

```
#include "CCriticalSection.h"
class CSingleLock {
    CCriticalSection *m_cs;
public:
    CSingleLock(CCriticalSection* cs = NULL, bool bLock = false)
    {
        m_cs = cs;
        if(m_cs != NULL)
        {
            if(bLock)
                m_cs->Lock();
        }
    }
    void Unlock()
    {
        if(m_cs != NULL)
            m_cs->Unlock();
    }
    void Lock()
    {
        if(m_cs != NULL)
            m_cs->Lock();
    }
    ~CSingleLock()
    {
        if(m_cs != NULL)
            m_cs->Unlock();
    }

};
```

Comment: `1` any reason to not use ATL/MFC classes [`CComAutoCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50yhb8t7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and friends? `2` the second class is just inaccurate, e.g. it might so happen you unlock without locking. Handy helper classes are not designed this way.

Comment: @RomanR. I avoid ATL/MFC if I'm working on non-commercial projects because they don't come with VS Express.  (They never used to anyway, I haven't checked in VS 2012.)

Comment: @arx: the question is tagged [tag:mfc] and the poster used to ask [tag:atl] questions in past.

Comment: Because I 've been asked to get MFC/ATL out of a a library that made use of them..and I've already done that, while working on windows 7, and now I get this problem while testing on XP.

Comment: You did not post the code which causes the issue. The classes above are are not robust, they can cause the issues if incorrectly used. You need to look into your higher level code. A typical issue is unlocking never locked section, and deleting locked section. A better class would get `assert`s to report on this.

Comment: @RomanR. you just solved the problem, while looking at the higher level code I've noticed that there was a case when a CSingleLock was created and Released and after that its destructor called unlock again on it, I apologize to all that replied for not being more specific about this, the library that I work with does take care that the CsingleLocks that are created within a thread are accessed only by creator threads, the problem was indeed with the double calling of Unlock on the critical section, thank you all for bringing the knowledge. Now, how do I check if a crit sect is locked?

Comment: Whould the solution above be alright? It works but is ok, I am missing anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the locking class really helpful, you need to improve it like this:

```
class CSingleLock 
{
    CCriticalSection *m_cs;
    bool m_bLock;

public:
    CSingleLock(CCriticalSection* cs = NULL, bool bLock = false)
    {
        m_cs = cs;
        if(m_cs != NULL)
        {
            if(bLock)
                m_cs->Lock();
            m_bLock = bLock;
        }
    }
    void Unlock()
    {
        if(!m_cs || !m_bLock)
            return;
        m_cs->Unlock();
        m_bLock = false;
    }
    void Lock()
    {
        if(!m_cs || m_bLock)
            return;
        m_cs->Lock();
        m_bLock = true;
    }
    ~CSingleLock()
    {
        Unlock();
    }
};
```

It should be intelligent enough to keep you away from trouble of incorrect CS use.

Comment: Note that `m_bLock` is uninitialized by the constructor if `cs` is NULL.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: with `!m_cs`, `m_bLock` is never accessed.

Comment: @RomanR. Unless, for instance, the user adds a `Set()` method which sets the critical section after construction, and neglects to initialize the flag.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: You are correct, of course, my stroke was to add lock check with minimal effort. If I had to choose, `m_cs` would be definitely `CCriticalSection&`.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says "If a thread calls `LeaveCriticalSection` when it does not have ownership of the specified critical section object, an error occurs that may cause another thread using `EnterCriticalSection` to wait indefinitely.".

The destructor for `CSingleLock` calls `CriticalSection::Unlock` which calls `LeaveCriticalSection` but there's no check that the critical section is held by the current thread.

You need to keep track of ownership of the critical section.

Comment: Why don t I get the deadlock on windows 7?

Comment: I really have the situation you described in your answer.. but I need the CSingleLock object to be accessible from multiple threads, because it blocks other possible threads from accessing a common array structure

Comment: Maybe it does deadlock and you just haven't seen it yet or maybe it fails in a more pernicious fashion (e.g. it doesn't protect the shared resource).  It doesn't matter, the code is broken.  More constructively, if CSingleLock is shared, why does the destructor call Unlock?

Comment: @A.K "An error occurs that *may* cause another thread to wait indefinitely." It says that the hang *may* occur, not *will* occur. Leaving a critical section you do not own leads to undefined behavior, so anything can happen. Appearing to work is a valid form of undefined behavior. So is appearing to work for 5 minutes, then mysteriously crashing.